# Structuring a series of notes in ConTeXt

Tags: context

Complete ConTeXt beginner here. I'm trying to set up a project to structure all my course notes for this coming semester. I've already read the page on the [wiki](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Project_structure) and the ConTeXt magazine #1101, but I still have a few questions and a few problems.

I have the following file structure

```
year1-semester1/
  project_year1-semester1.tex 
  environments/
    env_font.tex
  products/
    analysis/
      prd_analysis.tex
      chap1/
        c_chap1.tex
```

where the files are

```
% project_year1-semester1.tex
\startproject project_year1-semester1

\usepath[environments]
\environment env_font

\usepath[products]
\product analysis/prd_analysis

\stopproject
```

```
% env_font.tex
\startenvironment env_font

\setupbodyfont[pagella]
\setupbodyfont[12pt]

\stopenvironment
```

```
% prd_analysis.tex
\startproduct prd_analysis
\project project_year1-semester1
\usepath[chap1]

\component c_chap1

\stopproduct
```

```
% c_chap1.tex
\startcomponent c_chap1
\product prd_analysis
\starttext

\startchapter
  [title={A chapter}]

\startformula
  1 + 1 = \mathrm{fish}
\stopformula

\stopchapter

\stoptext
\stopcomponent
```

The problem is that if I compile either `c_chap1.tex` or `prd_analysis.tex`, I'd expect `env_font.tex` to be called at some point, which would set the font to Tex Gyre Pagella (palatino), but that doesn't happen. What am I doing wrong?

Also:

1. in `prd_analysis.tex` if I need to include 10 chapters I'd need to `\usepath[chap1,chap2,....,chap10]`. Is there a way to use globbing like I would in a shell? Something like `\usepath[chap*]`.
2. in `prd_analysis.tex` and `c_chap1.tex`, it doesn't matter if I omit `\starttext ... \stoptext`. Why is that?

Comment: 1. I recommend to put all chapters in the same folder because each folder makes the compilation slower. 2. You don't need `\starttext` because `\startproduct` and `\startcomponent` add another `\starttext` to the document.

Comment: 1. I'm usually going to be working on and compiling the single components, so the con of having slower compilation times for the whole document should be outweighed by the pro of having a cleaner file tree; 2. got it, thanks. What about the environment file though, why is it not being picked up?

Comment: When you use `\usepath` to set folder where ConTeXt should search these paths always start in the folder where your main document is which is either the product or the component file. This means your `\usepath[environments]` tells ConTeXt there is a subdirectory name `environments` and the product directory while you actually need this setup: `\usepath[../../environments]`.

Comment: Oh, this also means that in `project_year1-semester1.tex` I don't need to specify `\usepath[products]` and `\product analysis/prd_analysis` should just be `\product prd_analysis`, right? Btw, with `\usepath[../../environments]` I know get palatino in `prd_analysis.tex` but `c_chap1.tex` and `c_chap2.tex` are still in Latin Modern. How do I fix that as well?

Comment: You can remove `\usepath[products]` because the product loads the project file and `\product ...`lines are ignored anyway. When you process a component file you have to add another `../` to the path settings, e.g. `\usepath[../../../environments]` because you have another level to go up.

Comment: Adding `\usepath[../../../environments]` to `project_year1-semester1.tex` doesn't seem to have any effect on the components, they're still not using palatino.

Comment: 1. You forgot to load the project file from your components. 2. ConTeXt goes only two levels up to look for project or component files but you need three for your components. 3. You can fix both when you tell ConTeXt where it can find the project file with `\project [../../../project_year1-semester1]` (the brackets are optional)

Comment: Ok that works, but why do I have to load the project file in my components? I thought it worked like this: you load the product file in the components, when you compile a component it calls the product, the product calls the project, and the project calls the environments. If I have to include the project in the components, then why do I also have to include the product? In other words, in `c_chap1.tex` what does `\product prd_analysis` do?

Comment: In the past it was possible to use project files as main document where `\product ...` loaded other files but this has changed and projects are more or less useless, the only thing they can be used for is to load environment files. When you process a component `\product ...` serves no purpose except as metadata and it wouldn't make sense to load the files, because the product would then load the component again and we create a loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks for all the infos. Except for putting all the components together, would you structure this any differently? I'm open to suggestions. Btw, where can I read more about this? The only sources I've found are the wiki page on ConTeXtGarden and the issue #1101 of the ConTeXt magazine, but a lot of what you've told me here is in neither of them.

Comment: When you have ConTeXt related problems the [ConTeXt mailing list](https://mailman.ntg.nl/mailman/listinfo/ntg-context) is the better place to ask your questions.

Comment: I subscribed to the mailing list two days ago, but writing code via email, without a way to highlight `code` from text and without *any* kind of **markup** seems so inconvenient.